# How to change the text of a button to a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>) as! TableViewCell
    cell.myButton. =  recipies[indexPath.row]
}
```

I don't know what to add after `cell.mybutton.`.

The top part of this code is also labeled as incorrect in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

nice and simple

```
cell.myButton.setTitle(recipies[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.  Instead, flag them as duplicates.

Comment: It says "Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'setTitle' -- Lol, please help me I'm new to Xcode

Comment: OK - you have a different problem, and it looks like myButton is **not** actually defined as a UIButton.  Could you include the code where you define 'myButton' - either where you create it myButton = UIButton ... or the outlet that you attach to?